# device not ready event not fired using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

i have been written this code in main.js and adding this file index.html but on android emulator events everything working correctly but on device ready event showing error on cat log that device ready event not fired i am not understanding where i am wrong is there any problem with this code .

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // setup global error handler
        window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNumber) {
            console.log([lineNumber, url, message].join(" "));
            return false;
        };

        window.isphone = false;
        if(document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1 
            && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1) {
            window.isphone = true;
        }

        if(window.isphone) {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        } else {
            onDeviceReady();
        } 

        console.log("document.ready");
        console.log(window.location.hash);

        // start the app
    });

    function onDeviceReady() {
        app.init();
    }

    var app = app || { _timeStart: null };

    app.init = function () {

//events binding
        });     
    };
```

Comment: You need to rearrange you code a little there. `deviceready` should be the first thing you attach and listen for as it is the first event that will fire, it fires even before `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Andrew i did'nt get your point can u update that place in my code where u specifying change in my code.

Comment: It should look something like this: http://pastebin.com/7xLmSQGR

Comment: is it ok now
var mainApp = {
    
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true);
    },
    
    onDeviceReady: function() {
  console.log('event Fired');
        app.init();
    },
};

and i am calling this mainApp.initialize from my index.html before body tag when 
like

<script type="text/javascript">
      
      mainApp.initialize();
          
 </script>
</body>
</html>